# How to Enable DefaultTimeToLive ( TTL ) at a collection level for documentdb when the collection is already existing ?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have tried using :-
  collection.DefaultTimeToLive = CloudSettings.GetDataRetentionPeriod() * 86400;
  collection.SetPropertyValue("DefaultTTL", CloudSettings.GetDataRetentionPeriod() * 86400);

But its not enabling the TTL property as we can see from the azure portal

Answer (score 0):

For me, DefaultTimeToLive works:

```
collection.DefaultTimeToLive = <your-value-here>;
var response = await _client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection, request.RequestOptions);
```